# Como mantener el valor seleccionado en una select despues del post back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Hola como puedo pantener el valor seleccionado de una select despues del postback?
 este es el codigo que tengo en la vista:

```
<select id="LocalidadId" name="LocalidadId" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" asp-items="ViewBag.LocalidadId">
    <option>Selecciona una localidad</option>
</select>
```

Este es el codigo en el controlador:

```
ViewData["LocalidadId"] = new SelectList(await queryLocalidades.ToListAsync(), "LocalidadId", "Localidad1", null, "Municipio1");
```

Despues de realizar un submit; de nuevo se establece en el select el valor por default: "Selecciona una localidad", pero mi deseo es que se mantenga en el select la localidad seleccinada despues del submit para poder realizar operaciones de filtrado y ordenado en esa localidad en especifico. Espero que me halla explicado bien y que me puedan orientar.

Comment: Esto no es asp.net-mvc, es webforms

Comment: Es ASP.NET Core (MVC 6) TagHelper Select, helper mas potente que HtmlDropDownList Helper. Pero no se como mantener el valor seleccionado despues del postback

Answer (score 1):

Intenta obtener el valor seleccionado del control y en el `SelectList` buscar cual item es el que tiene ese valor y asignarle la propiedad `Selected` a true:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(await queryLocalidades.ToListAsync(), "LocalidadId", "Localidad1", null, "Municipio1");


// obtienes el valor seleccionado cuando se hizo el postback
var valorSeleccionado = obtenerValorSeleccionadoSelectList();
foreach(var item in selectList)
{
  if(item.Value == valorSeleccionado)
  {
     item.Selected = true;
  }
}

// signas el select list al control
ViewData["LocalidadId"] = selectList;
```